# An ORM Without Session

Tags: .net

i am worked with NHibernate, XPO, SubSonic, DataObject.net. but as you know all of this ORM's need Session opening and closing in programming blocks,
Working with Database sessions in business logic layer and UI Layer is not a correct manner from the Software engineering aspect. so i am going to change my ORM to something that is not need for Session or unitofwork in every piece of my Application.

do you have any suggestion ?

also, i tried EF4 POCO, but it have some problems and i could not find a forum/support center to ask my questions yet !

---

The problem is i think in the upper layers of UI and Logic , i should not involve my code into session creation and dispose. i want ORM works transparently. Specially XPO forced me to work heavily with sessions in UI forms ! i dont think its a right manner

Comment: It seems more likely you're misunderstanding how to use these libraries, if _all_ of them have a similar programming paradigm and expectations of you, but you find them all to be "not a correct manner."

Comment: I don't really agree - the unit of work for example can be very well defined from the context of the UI. For instance a single screen, or a workflow can be associated with a single unit of work.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that almost every ORM relies on some connection between the models and some sort of database session.  I think the very bleeding edge of EF4 has made some strides towards independence (I think they call them object-first entities, but I'm not sure).  Their self-tracking entities were a start, but they relied on serialization or manipulation in order to begin tracking.

The problem is that there is an "impedance mismatch" between OO entities and relational databases that cannot be overcome without serious work.  You can get almost complete separation of your concerns, but you lose efficientcy.  You can be very efficient, but you are constantly aware you're dealing with a database.

The solution is that there is no solution, and you need to accept this.  Deal with it as best and as appropriately as you can, but forget the idea that you can completely abstract away your database.  It just isn't practical or possible with current technologies.